# Populate a dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary that would look like this:

```
{'area1': ['x1_area1', 'x2_area1'], 'area2': ['x1_area2', 'x2_area2']}
```

I'm trying to use a for loop:

```
dict_ ={}
keys =["area1","area2"]
for key in keys : 
    dict_ = {key : ["x1_"+ key,"x2_"+ key]}
    dict_.update(dict_)
```

But I get this output:

```
{'area2': ['x1_area2', 'x2_area2']}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
keys =["area1","area2"]
dict_ = {}
for key in keys : 
    dict_[key] = ["x1_"+ key,"x2_"+ key]
    
dict_
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
res = {k: [f'{x}_{k}' for x in ('x1', 'x2')] for k in keys}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'area1': ['x1_area1', 'x2_area1'], 'area2': ['x1_area2', 'x2_area2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, you’re redefining `dict_` and thus overwriting the existing values. Use a different variable name, or just inline its usage entirely:

```
dict_ = {}
keys = ["area1", "area2"]
for key in keys:
    dict_.update({key : ["x1_" + key, "x2_" + key]})
```

This is taking over 100% of your code and just fixing the specific issues. There are better, more “Pythonic” solutions for this problem, which are explained in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The original code overrides the first value.

The following code will update without override:

```
keys =["area1","area2"]

dict_ = {}
for key in keys :
    x = {key : ["x1_"+ key,"x2_"+ key]}
    dict_.update(x)

# {'area1': ['x1_area1', 'x2_area1'], 'area2': ['x1_area2', 'x2_area2']}
print(dict_)
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at how to add items to a dictionaries, it seems like `dict_[key] = "answer"`
is the way to go.

```
dict_ = {}
keys = ["area1", "area2"]
for key in keys:
    dict_[key] = ["x1_" + key, "x2_" + key]
print(dict_)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp